# SharePoint 2013 Wiki page Table Layout whitespace

Tags: css, sharepoint-2013, wiki

When I hide the left navigation (quick launch) I get a large amount of white space between the far left column and center,  I'm using a three column layout on a wiki page. I tried adding CSS to CEWP. Any thoughts on how to fix the issue?

[![SharePoint wiki page with whitespace between left and center column
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGut3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGut3.png)

```css
 .ms-core-navigation { DISPLAY: none } #contentBox { margin-left: 0px } 


.ms-core-navigation { DISPLAY: none }
#contentBox { margin-left: 200px }


.ms-webpartzone-cell,
.ms-webpart-zone {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.ms-wikicontent ms-rtestate-field {
     padding-right: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: Please share the modified .css & a screenshot of the same. I'll work on it.

Comment: Dev - A screen shot and the CSS used is attached. Thanks.

Comment: You need to add a css onCollapse & make sure you mark it as !important E.g: margin-right:0 !important;